# MicrosoftOnline Migration - Why do I have to wait several minutes before I can click "Finish?"

Tags: email, performance, exchange, migration

I'm using the Microsoft Online Internet E-Mail Mailbox Migration Wizard. I'm moving my email from several GMail accounts to my Microsoft Exchange Online mailboxes. Every time I migrate all or part of a GMail mailbox, I have to wait about five minutes after it completes migration before the `Finish` button becomes available.

What is going on during this time? Is it something I am doing wrong, or is the system just slow?